# Ссылки на отдельных словах в тексте из базы данных

Tags: java, android

Есть текст, который выводится в TextView из базы данных. Возможно ли, реализовать ссылки на отдельных словах с этом тексте?

Comment: поясните, пожалуйста. вам нужно позиционировать текст в определенное место, или вам нужно обрабатывать клики на отдельные слова?

Comment: @tse обрабатывать клики на отдельные слова